# Improper integrals examples

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have read that
Out of existence  for an improper integral
$ \int_{0}^{ \infty} f(x) dx $ for a continuous function $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $  it doesn't imply that $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =0$ and that $f$ doesn't even have to be limited.

Can you think of any good examples for $f$ ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Between $n$ and $n+1$, $f$ can have a thin peak of width $1/n^3$ and height $n$, so the integral on this interval is at most $1/n^2$. So it is integrable (the improper integral converges) but it does not tend to 0 and is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $f(x)=\cos(x^2)$ is an example where the integral exists, but the series doesn't converge (because $\cos(n^2)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, and thus doesn't converge to $0$). If you substitute $x\to t^2$, you'll get an example with an unbounded integrand.